# Making an NSDecimal for CorePlot

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I have a coreplot item y.majorIntervalLength which I believe to be of type NSDecimal.  I need to fill it with a value that I calculate from a couple of doubles.  The problem is when I go to assign the resulting double to y.majorIntervalLength I get:

Incompatible type for Argument 1...

I do not know how to convert a value from a double to an NSDecimal which is what I gather is required for the y.majorIntervalLength.

How do I package/wrap/cast  this value to the correct format?

What do I need to read to learn this kind of thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Plot includes an extensive set of utility functions for converting values to and from NSDecimal. Look in the CPTUtilities header file or docs.

For your example:

```
y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromDouble(2.5);
```

Comment: Yes, if you're using an old version of Core Plot. Starting with version 2.0, the `majorIntervalLength` property changed type to `NSNumber`. There's a document on the [Core Plot wiki](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Core-Plot-API-Changes-Between-Versions-1.x-and-2.x) that describes the version 2.0 API changes.